# Second level cache for entities with where clause

Tags: hibernate, caching

I am wondering where the hibernate second level cache works as expected if I put a where clause in the hbm.xml class definition:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.clazzes.A" table="TABLE_A"
   mutable="false" where="xyz=5" >
  <cache usage="read-only"/>
  <id name="id"  />
  ...
```

Will hibernate still put the id as key into the cache, or do I have enable the query cache? E.g. when I then execute a HQL query like `from A where id=2` that results in an SQL similar to `select * from TABLE_A where id=2 and (xyz=5)`. If I execute this query twice, will it consider the second level cache, or will it nevertheless execute the SQL twice?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have to enable the query cache. this is a per query setting, so you have enough control over it.

Comment: which means that hibernate is unable to identify that all instances of the class have xyz=5?